# For ArcGIS tool can Illustration of Item Description be used as Thumbnail in Contents of Catalog window?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, thumbnail

I've made a Python script tool using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 SP2 and have accessed its Item Description to Update its Illustration by browsing to a *.png file.  The expected Illustration then appears in Item Description.

However, when I use the Catalog window, to access Thumbnail view of the Toolset in which that tool sits, the Illustration does NOT appear as its Thumbnail.  Am I perhaps missing a step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now the subject of an [ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bvV9AAI) so if anyone else is looking for it, please vote.